# Is there a reason why my huggingface model is not generating the summary in an asyncio event loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, huggingface-transformers, background-task

I am trying to process a CSV file from streamlit frontend which has a list of URLs which I am pre-processing using nltk  to pass to a hugging face transformer for summarization. I want to create a background task using asyncio and ProcessPoolExecutor  for this and return the taskid to the UI for polling the results which are stored individually for each URL in a text file on the backend storage. I cannot figure out why my model is not being invoked when I use a background async task at all, it doesn't output any errors or logs.When I call the model in a synchronous fashion for the first URL in the file it returns an output, not sure why it doesnt get invoked when its in the async event loop. Here is my main.py which receives a CSV file and invokes the inference function.

```
class Job(BaseModel):
uid: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
status: str = "in_progress"
processed_urls: List[str] = Field(default_factory=list)

app = FastAPI()
nlp = NLP()
jobs: Dict[UUID, Job] = {}


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
return {"message": "Welcome from the API"}

@app.post("/{contentType}", status_code=HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED)

async def get_summary(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, contentType: 
str, file: UploadFile = File(...)):

df = pd.read_excel(file.file.read(), index_col=None, header=None)
model_name = config.MODEL_NAMES[contentType]
start = time.time()
name = f"/storage/{str(uuid.uuid4())}.txt"
new_task = Job()
jobs[new_task.uid] = new_task
background_tasks.add_task(generate_remaining_summaries, new_task.uid, 
model_name, name, df)
return new_task

async def generate_remaining_summaries(uid: UUID, model_name, name, df):
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
jobs[uid].result = await event_loop.run_in_executor(
    executor, partial(generate_summary, uid, model_name, name, df))
jobs[uid].status = "complete"


def generate_summary(task_id: UUID, model_name, name, df):
logger.info("model_name in generate_summary " + model_name)
for ind in range(len(df)):
    url = df.iat[ind + 1, 0]
    
    article_text = get_text(url)
    summary = nlp.inference(model_name, article_text)
    name = name.split(".")[0]
    name = f"{name.split('_')[0]}_{ind}.txt"
    logger.info("name " + name)
    with open(name, 'w+') as file1:
        for listItem in summary:
            file1.write('%s\n' % listItem)
    jobs[task_id].processed_urls.append(name)
jobs[task_id].status = "completed"


 @app.get("/work/{uid}/status")
 async def status_handler(uid: UUID):
 return jobs[uid]


if __name__ == "__main__":
 uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080) 

> Inference.py

import transformers
from transformers import BartTokenizer, BartForConditionalGeneration

import nltk
import torch
import logging.config
import os
import config
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

nltk.download('punkt')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
 transformers.logging.set_verbosity_info()


def nest_sentences(document):
 nested = []
 sent = []
 length = 0
 for sentence in nltk.sent_tokenize(document):
    length += len(sentence)
    if length < 1024:
        sent.append(sentence)
    else:
        nested.append(sent)
        sent = [sentence]
        length = len(sentence)

  if sent:
    nested.append(sent)

  return nested


 class NLP:
   def __init__(self):
    self.cache_dir = os.environ["MODEL_DIR"] + "facebook/bart-large-cnn/"
    self.tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-cnn", 
    cache_dir=self.cache_dir)
    self.model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-cnn", 
    cache_dir=self.cache_dir)
    self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

  def generate_summary(self, nested_sentences):
    logger.info("Inside inference before generate summary")
    
    summaries = []
    for nested in nested_sentences:
        input_tokenized = self.tokenizer.encode(' '.join(nested), truncation=True, 
     return_tensors='pt')
        input_tokenized = input_tokenized.to(self.device)
        summary_ids = self.model.to(self.device).generate(input_tokenized,
                                                        length_penalty=3.0)
        output = [self.tokenizer.decode(g, skip_special_tokens=True, 
                 clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False) for g in
                  summary_ids]
        summaries.append(output)

       summaries = [sentence for sublist in summaries for sentence in sublist]
       return summaries

def inference(self, model_name, article_text):
    
    nested = nest_sentences(article_text)
    logger.info(nested)
    summarized_text = self.generate_summary(nested)
    logger.info("Inside inference summarized text")
    logger.info(summarized_text)
    nested_summ = nest_sentences(' '.join(summarized_text))
    return self.generate_summary(nested_summ)
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation? The code is very hard to read when some of it isn’t indented.

Comment: @dirn Is this better now ? Sorry new to stackoverflow and don't really know the norms for indenting.

Comment: Seems you're running the function partial, although I can't find where it's defined jobs[uid].result = await event_loop.run_in_executor(
    executor, partial(generate_summary, uid, model_name, name, df))

Comment: @Isabi Thanks for your input, generate_summary is defined right after the run_in_executor call. Do you think partial is causing the issue? What does partial do?